# Java test adding values from an Enum to an arrayList

Tags: java, testing, arraylist, enums

The arrayList `politicCard` of the class `Player` contains values from the enum `Color`, to test it i added three different values but it returns an error, isn't `player.getPoliticCards().get(0)` supposed to return the color value in position 0 that i added before?

```
public enum Color {
    BLUE, BLACK, JOKER
}
public class Player {
    private int id;
    private ArrayList<Color> politicCards;
    public Player(int id){
        this.setId(id);
    }
    public ArrayList<Color> getPoliticCards() {
        return politicCards;
    }
    public void setPoliticCards(ArrayList<Color> politicCards) {
        this.politicCards = politicCards;
    }   

}
public class PlayerTest {
    @Test
    public void PoliticCardsTest(){
        Player player = new Player(1);
        player.getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLACK);
        player.getPoliticCards().add(Color.BLUE);
        player.getPoliticCards().add(Color.JOKER);
        assertEquals(Color.BLACK,player.getPoliticCards().get(0));
    }

}
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: @Reimeus NullPointerException

Comment: You have to intialize your array @mpz!!! :)

Comment: Just a side node: This is not a good design, you are exposing the internals of your class to be freely edited from externally. Goolge for 'encapsulation' and you find easily some tutorials explaining the matter.

Comment: politicCards is not initialized and hence its giving NullPointerException
public Player(int id){
        this.setId(id);
this.politicCards = new ArrayList<PlayerTest.Color>();
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `politicCards` field is not initialized, you could add 
`plater.setPoliticCards(new ArrayList<Color>());` after `player` construction.